# Delete delete wrong repository in xcode

Tags: ios, svn

[image]

i want to add repository svn like this https://*.*.*.*/svn/IOS/xxxx

but the xcode always change it to this: https://*.*.*.*/svn/IOS

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like XCode is saying that it wants you to enter the URL to the root of your repository. It then provides a UI that will let you browse and select the path within the repository that you want to checkout.  This might just be for UI reasons so that, for example, if you want to access /branches or /tags later you can do so via the same UI.